# Sharepoint 2013_web Analytcis Usage Reporting The Event Store folder in not created any log file in it

Tags: sharepoint-2013

**Event Store folder is empty**

I'm having troubles getting the popularity reports to show any information, they only show 0's for all days.
I've narrowed the problem down to the Event Store files not being created:

[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kxCr.png).

I can see the .usage files being created and disappearing in the Request Usage folder but no recent dated folders in the Event Store. The Event Store folder id totally empty.

Other items of information:

- Usage Data Import & Usage Data Processing jobs succeed
- All timer jobs running properly
- Logging folder is updating fine
- AE folder is also updating properly

Only issue with Event store folder in which files are not being created

[Event store folder is empty.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pijwv.png)

Please help.

Comment: Recently we patched our SP2013 and found the popularity trend is stopped (it works before). EventStore is not update since the date of patch. Everything else is updating. It is exactly same as yours. May I know did you fix it?